# How to align a image to a paragraph to the right

Tags: html, css, image, bootstrap-4, alignment

```
    [scrollspy samp[scrollspy][1]le]
```

now having removed the padding in the about us section, the scrollspy is not aligning to the about us, i need help on how to fix the scollspy while maintaining the picture aligned to the paragraph.

```
</style>
      </head>
      <body id="#navbar" data-spy="scroll" data-target="navbar" data-offset="10">
          <nav id="#navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
              <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
                <img src="logo.png" alt="Logo" style="width:80px;">
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="navbar-nav">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#About Us">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#Services" class="nav-link">Services</a>
                      </li>    
                      <li class="nav-item">
                          <a href="#Porfolio" class="nav-link">Porfolio</a>
                        </li> 
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#Contact Us" class="nav-link">Contact Us</a>
                          </li> 


                  </ul>  

                </div>
```

Comment: You can also investigate [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) which would allow you to display the `div` and `img` as columns side by side

Comment: can you provide a complete snippet, all of `div class="container-fluid"` (you're missing 2 close `div` tags)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `padding-top:85px` style attribute from the "About Us" `div` - that creates a 85px high white space which apparently you don't want.

Also, the `h2` in there will have a relatively high default `top-margin` which also creates white space above the text, so you might want to add `margin-top: 0` to that `h2`.

Comment: thank you, when i remove the padding as you suggested it aligned the photo however when i click on the about us on the navigation it cuts the information as it scrolls down. Also where would i add the margin-top:0, as code? thank you

Comment: There is no navigation in the code you provided, so I can't help you there. Concerning the `margin: 0`: That would be added to the CSS for the `h2` element (which contains the "About Us" header)

Comment: ok, i have added the picture sample, please see above. also the updated code. Thank you!

Comment: You replaced the previous code in your question completely with new code – I think you should create a new question (and be more specific – there is no "picture sample", and you maybe should add an explanation what "scollspy" is – you can't expect people to start googling and researching the terms you use...